# How to change the time format?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use the `TIME` data type. And my data is displayed in the format `hh:mm:ss` (03:14:00). How can I display the data in the format `hh:mm` (03:14)? DATE type method does not work:

```
{{test.time | date: 'HH:mm'}}
```

It will simply produce such an error.

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "03:14:00" into a date'
>   for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: How is `test.time` defined on your ts file? According to [DatePipe docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#input-value), you should pass "a Date object, a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch), or an ISO string "

Comment: Create your own filter (moment could also help your life)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving it the start of any date, and concatenate the time onto that.

```
{{"1970-01-01T"+test.time | date: 'HH:mm'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, in a few minutes I will note the decision)

Answer (score 0):

May not be an apt solution. But one way can be to take the hh:mm:ss time into a string var and then split the string to remove the last 3 characters